# How to get original elasticsearch mapping property when aggregating with property hash

Tags: elasticsearch, search, hash

I have following kind of mapping.

```
    "clean_url": {
        "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
               "hash": {
                  "type": "murmur3"
               }
            },
            "index": "false"
        }
    }
```

Now in this case, I can do term aggregation in this fashion

```
"terms": {
    "field": "clean_url",
}
```

or

```
"terms": {
    "field": "clean_url.hash",
}
```

In the first case, the bucket key is clean_url, but in the second case key is clean_url.hash.

I want the original clean_url key in case I am doing aggregation on its hash. How can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```bash
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "per_url": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "clean_url.hash"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "value": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "clean_url",
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The`"size": 1` of the sub aggregation assumes that there is no hash collisions but this can be modified.

Depending of your data it should be fast enough.